# Please guide me to fix this Solididty error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, truffle, ganache

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czpiJ.png)

Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> project:/contracts/Crowdsale.sol

,Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: " to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> project:/contracts/MyToken.sol

CompileError: ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/GSN/Context.sol" not found
--> project:/contracts/Crowdsale.sol:3:1:
|
3 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/GSN/Context.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol" not found
--> project:/contracts/Crowdsale.sol:5:1:
|
5 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/math/SafeMath.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol" not found
--> project:/contracts/Crowdsale.sol:6:1:
|
6 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/SafeERC20.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol" not found
--> project:/contracts/Crowdsale.sol:7:1:
|
7 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'contract'
--> project:/contracts/MyTokenSale.sol:5:1:
|
5 | contract MyTokenSale is Crowdsale{
| ^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
at C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\compile-solidity\dist\run.js:95:1
at Generator.next ()
at fulfilled (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\compile-solidity\dist\run.js:28:43)
Truffle v5.5.30 (core: 5.5.30)
Node v16.16.0

Answer (score 0):

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

add this line in top of your solidity file

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to specify a license for your contract(s), you would mostly choose MIT License if your project is open source by adding this line to the top of your solidity contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

However, you can visit [this](https://choosealicense.com/) website to know which license is best for your project.

There are some other errors triggered by the compiler regarding your imports which you can fix by adding the right Open Zeppelin packages to your project.

If none of the above fixes your issue, I think it's best you share your smart contract code.